# Jenkins server delete older version of .m2 repository

Tags: maven, jenkins

We have a Jenkins server integrated with maven. In the server `C:\user\jenkins\.m2\repository\com\<project>\web-app\`

I have multiple folder like recent `1.0.700` to `1.0.10`. 
I would like to delete all the previous folder except recent `10`, like `1.0.700` till `1.0.690`.

I installed couple of plug-in like maven repository plug-in , but the folders are still present. Can anybody provide any links to the solution?

Comment: Go on the machine an simply remove the repo..It will be filled up by the next build. Apart from that using the jenkins users home location for different builds on the machine is not a good idea. Every build should have it's own local cache...can be configured in Jenkins job (use local to workspace repository).

Comment: I did manually, but I would like to this automatically. like tried some plug-ins like Maven repo clean but it is not working

Comment: I have tried different plug-ins available in Jenkins UI, but non of them seems to delete older version.

Comment: I too would like a UI way of doing this for AAA purposes. I don't trust everyone with access to the box Jenkins runs on